# ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 encoding issue

Tags: php, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am trying to replace a string which **does not have** any foreign characters in it with the string that **has** foreign keys in it.

If I do as I show in the following code:

```
$str= str_replace($original, utf8_encode($replace), $str);
```

or

```
$str= utf8_encode(str_replace($original, $replace, $str));
```

I get **FÃ©dÃ©ration** for **Fédération**

Any idea how to make str_replace or preg_replace to work with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is happening because you are utf8_encoding a string that is already in UTF-8 format.

Try to use this one:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($str));
```

This will find the current string format and encode it correctly.

PS: This way will prevent you to get your string buggy, then you can use the str_replace correctly.